# Php mysql LOWER function with AES_DECRYPT

Tags: php, mysql, database

I have AES encrypted data stored in the database using php mysql. Which I entered using AES_ENCRYPT. Problem is that data is coming from iphone and "first name" of member is coming with first letter in UPPER CASE and stored as Upper. For examle 'Pooja'

I am wondering when I go for searching the following then it does not give me any result.

```
SELECT *
FROM member
WHERE LOWER(AES_DECRYPT(fname,'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx')) LIKE'%$pooja%'
```

It gives me 'Pooja' when I dont use LOWER.

Can anybody please correct me here ??

Comment: Have you tried to output the result of `LOWER(AES...))`?

Comment: yes It does not output me to LOWER case.

Comment: can you give an example string that cannot be lowered?

Comment: By default MySQL has a case insensitive string comparison, so you may not need the LOWER and the issue might be with the decryption. What Collation are you using? I think the case sensitive ones have `_cs` suffixing them.

Comment: Note that binary collations are not the same as case-sensitive collations, although either may give you the result you want in this case. There's a cursory explanation [in the manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/charset-general.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure that you want to have the `%$` at the beginning?
As others have said, `LOWER` should ignore case, so try this:

```
SELECT * FROM member WHERE AES_DECRYPT(fname,'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx') LIKE 'pooja%';
```

`%` matches zero or more arbitrary characters, so this query should match all of the following

```
pooja
poojaaaa
pooja foo pooja bar
```

but not

```
pooj
pooj a
apooja
 pooja
```

Answer (score 6):

I had the same problem. I was trying to search for an email address in my DB. I had the user **EMAIL_ADDRESS@GMAIL.COM** in my **member_table**.

```
SELECT LOWER( AES_DECRYPT( email_address, 'my_key' ) USING 'utf8' )
FROM  `member_table` 
WHERE LOWER( AES_DECRYPT( email_address,  'my_key' ) USING 'utf8' ) LIKE 'EMAIL_ADDRESS@GMAIL.COM'
```

However, this did not worked because it always returned me the email address in upper case **EMAIL_ADDRESS@GMAIL.COM** despite the lower function and if a member inserted its email address as **email_address.com** that query wasn't able to find it.

So the solution was to use CONVERT( AES_DECRYPT( email_address,  'my_key' USING 'utf8' ). This allows me to find a member in an insensitive way (upper, lower or mixed) and I don't even need the LOWER function to compare. See example below:

```
SELECT LOWER( CONVERT( AES_DECRYPT( email_address, 'my_key' ) USING 'utf8' ) )
FROM  `member_table` 
WHERE CONVERT( AES_DECRYPT( email_address,  'my_key' ) USING 'utf8' ) LIKE 'EMaiL_AddreESS@Gmail.CoM'
```

The problem relates to: AES_ENCRYPT() encrypts the string str using a key key_str and **returns a binary string containing the encrypted output**, which does not work with LOWER function (As documented in mysql documentation here: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/encryption-functions.html#function_aes-decrypt)

Answer (score 0):

Had this problem too a few minutes ago. Have you tried to convert the decrypted string using `CONVERT(my_decrypted_string USING 'latin1')`?

AES_DECRYPT seems to return a binary string or something like that. With this type LOWER() does not work:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_lower